# most frequent vector that appears out of 1 million random vectors generated

Tags: matlab, vector

I would like to find the most frequent vector that appears out of 1 million generated.

The generated 1 by 7 vector would be `vec=sort(randperm(50,7));`

Thank you

Comment: To find the most frequent, the only thing I can think of is if you store all of them and use `mode`.  However, this will take a lot of memory.  Alternatively, you can convert each 7 into strings, then use these to create IDs to has into a lookup table and accumulate occurrences.  I won't provide an answer because you haven' tried anything.  Good luck!

Comment: @rayryeng: `unique` would be useful to OP once OP already has the required array of `10^6*7` elements.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I agree but didn't suggest it as you'd still need a lot of memory for it.

Comment: Can you compute something like the md5 number for each column and then use `unique` on the resulting vector?

Comment: Decided to write an answer.  It was an interesting problem, so I figured I'd write an answer for my own curiosity :) Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I guess I'll be nice enough and provide an answer.  I prematurely said that this will take up a lot of memory, but doing some rough calculations, you have a `1000000 x 7 = 7000000` numbers in total as you need 1 million 7-element arrays.  The total amount of memory required, assuming `double` numbers (which are 8 bytes per number) would be `7000000 x 8B = 56MB`, so yes we can handle this type of calculation.

High Performance Mark had a really insightful hint.  Basically, generate a `1000000 x 7` element array of random integers that range from 1 to 50 for each row, and ensure that they're sorted as you have stated in your post.

Once we do this, we can use [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) - specifically the first and third element of `unique` and use the `'rows'` flag for the function.  What this will do is that it will filter out your matrix over all of the rows and only produce unique rows which is exactly returned from the first element of `unique`.  The third output of `unique` tells you which row in the first output of `unique` that particular row in the original input matrix maps to.

When you're done, calculate the [`mode`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mode.html) of the third output of `unique`, which we can use to index into the first output of `unique`.  In other words:

```
% // Set seed for reproducibility
rng(1234);

%// For each row in our matrix, generate a random integer row of 7 elements ordered
A = arrayfun(@(x) sort(randperm(50,7)), 1:1000000, 'uni', 0);
B = vertcat(A{:});

%// Use unique in the fashion that I was talking about earlier
[C,~,counts] = unique(B,'rows');

%// Figure out which row occurs most frequently and show it:
frequent_vector = C(mode(counts),:);
disp(frequent_vector);
```

---

I set the random generator seed to `1234` so that you're able to reproduce the results on your end.  When dealing with random generation methods or anything dealing with randomness, it's always good to set a seed so that other people can reproduce your results.

Also, take note that I used [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) to call `randperm` 1000000 times as well as sorting each of those rows.  Because the output of `arrayfun` will be 1000000 cell arrays of `1 x 7` `double` arrays each, I use [`vertcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) to stack all of these arrays to finally get a `1000000 x 7` matrix.  I proceed to use `unique`, then calculate the `mode` of which vector occurs the most frequently, then display this vector.  As such, the output I get is:

```
frequent_vector =

     1    10    21    28    29    35    38
```

If you're curious to see how often the frequent vector occurs, you can specify an additional output to `mode` which tells you how often that particular vector occurs.  In other words:

```
[~,f] = mode(counts)

f = 

3
```

As such, this particular vector occurs 3 times and is the most occurring vector seen in your matrix.  Bear in mind that you are generating 1000000 7-element vectors, and so the probability of generating two of the same vector... even though you are sorting to ensure the proper order... is going to be very small, so don't be surprised if the most frequent vector doesn't occur that often.